# Вывод картинки из JSON

Tags: android, json, изображения

Получаю JSON ответ такого типа:

```
"avatar":"\/images\/def-avatar.png"
```

пытаюсь выводить так:

```
ava = urls.getString("avatar");    
URL url = new URL(ava);
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
                imageView5.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Не получается. Что делать будем?

Comment: Сделайте вывод URLа. И покажите вывод ошибки. Откуда картинка - из ресурсов или из внешнего источника (сайт, например)?

Comment: Вывод ошибки: "java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: /images/def-avatar.png". Картинку берем из сервера(сайта).

Comment: Ошибка прямо говорит, что мы скормили методу плохой URL. Во-первых, Вы отдали конструктору относительный(!) путь к файлу. Добавьте относительный путь (`ava`) к имени хоста (имя протокола (`http://`) + домен (`mydomain.ru`)), и попробуйте всё сделать так же.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел простой способ вывода изображений с помощью библиотеки Picasso.

Код выглядит так:

```
ava = urls.getString("avatar");
Picasso.with(this).load("http://www.*****.net"+ava).into(imageView5);
```

Answer (score 4):

> Вывод ошибки: "java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found:
>   /images/def-avatar.png". Картинку берем из сервера(сайта).

Ошибка прямо говорит, что мы скормили методу плохой URL. Во-первых, Вы отдали конструктору относительный(!) путь к файлу. Добавьте относительный путь (`ava`) к имени хоста (имя протокола (`http://`) + домен (`mydomain.ru`)), и попробуйте всё сделать так же.